# Cannot get simple boost networking example to work, merely initializing server causes errors immediately

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 and Boost 1.54.0. I've modified the chapter 4 example from [this book](http://www.amazon.ca/Boost-Asio-Network-Programming-John-Torjo/dp/1782163263) to be able to send arbitrary strings between client and server, but now the program just fails immediately.

This is the server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::asio;

io_service service;
size_t read_complete(
        char* buff, const boost::system::error_code& err, size_t bytes)
{
    if (err) {
        return 0;
    }
    bool found = std::find(buff, buff + bytes, '\n') < buff + bytes;
    return found? 0 : 1;
}

void handle_connections() {
    ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(
            service, ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(), 8001));
    std::string buff;
    while (true) {
        ip::tcp::socket sock(service);
        acceptor.accept(sock);
        int bytes = read(sock, buffer(buff.c_str()), bind(read_complete, buff, _1, _2));
        std::string msg(buff, bytes);
        sock.write_some(buffer(msg));
        sock.close();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    handle_connections();
}
```

It's copied directly from the book and has been verified to work correctly.

This is the minimal client necessary to reproduce the problem:

```
#include <memory>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;

class Client
{
    public:
        Client(const std::string& server, const std::string& port):
                server(server), port(port)
        {
            service = std::unique_ptr<io_service>(new io_service);
            endpoint = std::unique_ptr<ip::tcp::endpoint>(new ip::tcp::endpoint(
                    ip::address::from_string(server), atoi(port.c_str())));
            boostSocket = std::unique_ptr<ip::tcp::socket>(
                    new ip::tcp::socket(*service));
            std::cout << std::boolalpha << boostSocket.is_open();  // "false"
        }

    private:
        std::string server;
        std::string port;
        std::unique_ptr<io_service> service;
        std::unique_ptr<ip::tcp::socket> boostSocket;
        std::unique_ptr<ip::tcp::endpoint> endpoint;
};

int main()
{
    Client client("127.0.0.1", "8001");
    return 0;
}
```

Running this program tells me that the socket is never opened. So I dived into GDB and found this. For convenience, I have omitted the `(gdb) s` debugging commands I used between every set of lines.

```
Client::Client (this=0x7fffffffd7f8, server="127.0.0.1", port="8001")
    at DIRECTORY WHERE I STORED THE CPP FILE:14
14      service = std::unique_ptr<io_service>(new io_service);
    boost::asio::io_service::io_service (this=0x622130) at /usr/include/boost/asio/impl/io_service.ipp:41
41  {
    boost::asio::detail::noncopyable::noncopyable (this=0x622130) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/noncopyable.hpp:29
29    noncopyable() {}
    boost::asio::io_service::io_service (this=0x622130) at /usr/include/boost/asio/impl/io_service.ipp:39
39          (std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max)())),
    std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max () at /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/limits:1196
1196          max() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { return __LONG_MAX__ * 2UL + 1; }
    boost::asio::io_service::io_service (this=0x622130) at /usr/include/boost/asio/impl/io_service.ipp:41
41  {
    boost::asio::detail::service_registry::service_registry<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service, unsigned long> (this=0x622150, o=..., arg=18446744073709551615)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/service_registry.hpp:29
29  {
    boost::asio::detail::noncopyable::noncopyable (this=0x622150) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/noncopyable.hpp:29
29    noncopyable() {}
    boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex::posix_mutex (this=0x622158) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/posix_mutex.ipp:33
33  {
    boost::asio::detail::noncopyable::noncopyable (this=0x622158) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/noncopyable.hpp:29
29    noncopyable() {}
    boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex::posix_mutex (this=0x622158) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/posix_mutex.ipp:34
34    int error = ::pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_, 0);
```

The relevant lines are the first (because it's part of my code) and the last (it goes straight to error handling). Subsequent GDB commands only show that it delves further into Boost's error handling systems. Why? All I'm doing is creating an `io_service`.

Answer (score 1):

I have to fix errors in both the client and the server programs in order to even compile.

Here's the fixed server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::asio;

io_service service;
size_t read_complete(std::vector<char>const& buff, const boost::system::error_code &err, size_t bytes) {
    if (err) {
        return 0;
    }

    auto last = buff.begin()+bytes;
    bool found = (last != std::find(buff.begin(), last, '\n'));
    return found;
}

void handle_connections() {
    ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(service, ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(), 8001));

    std::vector<char> buff(1024);
    while (true) {
        ip::tcp::socket sock(service);
        acceptor.accept(sock);
        int bytes = read(sock, buffer(buff), bind(read_complete, boost::ref(buff), _1, _2));
        sock.send(buffer(buff, bytes));
        sock.close();
    }
}

int main() { handle_connections(); }
```

There were quite a number of changes, most notably the one fixing the buffer.

---

Here's the fixed client. I junked all the superstitious use of `new`:

```
#include <memory>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;

class Client {
  public:
    Client(const std::string &server, const std::string &port) 
        : server(server),
          port(port),
          service(),
          endpoint(ip::address::from_string(server), atoi(port.c_str())),
          boostSocket(service)
    {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << boostSocket.is_open() << "\n"; // of course, "false"
    }

  private:
    std::string server;
    std::string port;
    io_service service;
    ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint;
    ip::tcp::socket boostSocket;
};

int main() {
    Client client("127.0.0.1", "8001");
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- you should likely use the resolver to resolve address/port instead of just hardcoding the conversions (it might not be IP or port numbers)
- you never connect, so **of course** the socket is not open

  ```
  boostSocket.connect(endpoint);
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << boostSocket.is_open() << "\n"; // of connected, "true"

  /*
   *std::string message("hellow world\n\n\n\n\n");
   *boostSocket.send(buffer(message));
   *streambuf sb;
   *read(boostSocket, sb, boost::asio::transfer_all());
   *std::cout << "RESPONSE: '" << &sb << "'\n";
   */
  ```

Happy debugging

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. I had been connecting in another `Client.connect()` function. However, the error handling begins the moment the io_service is initialized, so I don't see why connecting in the constructor fixes anything.

Comment: Did you read the rest of my answer. Your code didn't even compile. Perhaps you should just try my code.

Comment: Please forgive me, sir. I'm new to networking. I barely understand any of it because there are a hundred and one things that can go wrong at every turn and it seems that if I modify the slightest thing from the examples it doesn't work. I appended your fixes to my code, and it didn't work; the client hung indefinitely. I ran your code exactly as you present it (placing the commented code into the constructor) and got an error: `read: connection reset by peer`. Please don't be angry with me. I just don't understand.

Comment: No problem. "connection reset by peer" just means that the connectionhas been reset by the peer (other end). This is normal happenstance if the other party just closes the socket.

Comment: But removing `sock.close()` from the server has no effect.